# SVG filter with 100% dimensioned feFlood not sizing correctly

Tags: css, svg, filter, svg-filters

I cannot understand why SVG filter is behaving the way it is behaving, when I am expecting different result.
Here is filter code:

```
<svg>
<defs>
<filter id="myFilter"> <feFlood result="floodFill" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="green" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="floodFill" mode="multiply"></feBlend> </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I apply it to the image this way:

```
<img style="filter: url(#myFilter);" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png">
```

I expect to see this:

[image]

But I actually see this:

[image]

The original image is this:

[image]

Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome, at least, the flood primitive 100%'s are being calculated as 100% of the default size of the containing SVG element - which when it's not dimensioned explicitly is 300px x 150px - the default size for all HTML replaced elements including img, object and iframe.

If you remove the sizing from your feFlood - it will apply the flood to the area of the filtered element + 10% overflow (default filter region). If you want to get rid of the overflow, then you should explicitly size your filter.

(This also works in Firefox. Edge doesn't support CSS filters, so if you want it to work in Edge, you have to move your image into the SVG body using the SVG `<image>` tag and apply the filter as an attribute.)

```html
<svg>
<defs>
<filter id="myFilter" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
  <feFlood result="floodFill" flood-color="green" flood-opacity="1">
  </feFlood>
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="floodFill" mode="multiply"></feBlend> </filter>
</defs>
</svg>

<img style="filter: url(#myFilter);" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png">
```

Comment: Good point. But I still can see flooded layer going out of image space like it has some intents or margins. What what that be there? It doesn't matter if I specify sizing or not

Comment: There is a 10% overflow by default in filters. You can constrain to the original box by adding x/y/width/height explicitly - which I've now added.